# Why no one can climb Mount Kailash?

Tags: scripture, shiva

I have read a lot about it that even if it is not the highest mountain on the planet  there is something which makes this mount unique because when ever a person goes there to climb on it, either there is so much snowfall that one has to back off or else some how their plan cancels.

It is amazing that no one has ever been able to even start climbing mount Kailash.

I want to know is there anything in hinduism which says something about it?

Comment: This has nothing to with Hindu Scriptures. Chinese Government didn't allow, considering Hindu and Buddhist sentiments.

Comment: @TheDestroyer In 1926, Hugh Ruttledge, **Reinhold Messner was given the opportunity** by the Chinese government to climb in the mid-1980s, In 2001 the Chinese **gave permission for a Spanish team to climb the peak**, These are just a few names of many more.

Comment: But  Reinhold Messner said he could climb it. I think it is climbable.

Comment: Yes sir, as a science student it seems what could possibly go wrong. but from a Hinduism perspective there are only two places in the world which are most powerful in terms of everything 1. Mount Kailash 2. some mountains in Tamil Nadu but the most powerful is Kailash. it is experienced by sadguru (I am not a fan, but sure he has better perception than us)

Comment: Yes. That's what i'm saying. We can't decide whether the mountain is climbable or not. But you question says it is not climbable. Many Rishis went to Kailash and met Lord Shiva, though we need spiritual virtues to meet Kailasa Shankara.

Comment: Every mountain is sacred. From Kailasa to Mahendragiri in South, there are innumerable mountains. It just depends on one's own perception. We can't reduce number to two. Kailasa no doubt is powerful being abode to Mahadeva but still there are innumerable mountains both in gross and subtle plains.

Comment: My Prime minister says there are several devas but one Maha Devas, we hindus have many festivals but Maha-Shivratri, So may be all mountain are sacred one can be Maha-Sacred. Any ways @TheDestroyer always uses Maha-Devas Display picture(there must be a thought after it, right?) There has to be something about this person who was know as MahaDev

Comment: Who is your Prime minister @TheDestroyer 's prime minister is your prime minister. We are of same country.

Comment: @SreeCharan Yes he may be yours too, But he is mine as well...:) And I respect him for his loyal Patriotism

Comment: Rishi- Nice question. I think its possible to find some reasons as to why its not possible, in the Puranas.

Comment: @Rickross thanks and this community also expect's a good answer from you and "The destroyer".

Comment: @@Rishi I don't think that i can answer this one. But may be destroyer can because i feel that the reasons  may have been explained in Shiva and/or similar Puranas and destroyer has read them thoroughly.

Comment: Mount Kailash is considered a living murthi. Do you climb on murthis in a temple?? If the murthi is in the shape of a mountain does that make it ok to climb on?